# The "Special Mask Mode" in 8259A with OCW3 (PIC : Programmable Interrupt Controller)

Tags: operating-system

The manual for 8259A says that

> In the special Mask Mode, when a mask bit is set in OCW1, it inhibits further interrupts at that level and enables interrupt from all other levels (lower as well as higher level) that are not masked.
>
> Thus, any interrupts may be selectively enabled by loading the mask register.

Do the operating system use this mode when the kernel sets up the PIC? If no then the lower priority interrupts would get a bit lower benefit. Like the keyboard gets more benefit than the FDD. Is the hardware interrupt mapping to the cascaded PIC in the system assigned/hard wired in the order of the importance.

Special Mask Mode or Normal Mask Mode, Which mode would get better performance or some benefit.

Suggestion on implementation of the Special Mask Mode when configuring the PIC for an x86 PC system would help me decide if i should use it or not.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Any. For example Linux.

Comment: Well i used this controller on bare metal systems only, where i wrote everything, but i assume it uses. Although, initializing this controller was the FIRST thing i did, since interrupt handling is the most basic thing you need in system.

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz: I wrote a toy kernel from scratch and while writing the interface and configuring this piece of hardware and wondered how and why this is used in real implementation, if it is used.

Comment: There are many possible solutions, even with this as only possibility (not to mention other controllers), I don't know why is that information important. Are you trying to make something compatible with existing software?

Comment: Just wondering if it is any use in the OS. In other implementations like using this chip in some other hardware configuration it can be useful, but is this feature used in Linux or other general purpose OSes?